# Is there any performance gain while using HQL over Criteria in Hibernate 3.6.10.Final

Tags: performance, hibernate, hql, criteria

I had the below query in Criteria which was taking 2 mins to to execute (return from the method)

```
public final Data getData(final Long dataid) {
    Criteria dataCriteria = session.createCriteria(Data.class)
    .setFetchMode("mgr")
    .setFetchMode("tmgr")
    .setFetchMode("comp")
    .createAlias("myent","myent", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("myent.party", "pardata", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("slabs","slabs", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("tpr", "tpr", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("tpr.par", "par",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("par.LE_EN", "le",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("le.RAT", "ler",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("c","c",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("c.crd","crd",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("crd.coc", "coc",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("coc.thpr","cocthpr",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("cocthpr.par", "cocpar",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("dataid", dataid));
    return (Data) dataCriteria.uniqueResult();

}
```

I refactored this to an HQL and now it takes 10 seconds to return from the method/execute the query. Below is the HQL version.

```
public final Data getData(final Long dataid) {        
    StringBuffer qbuffer = new StringBuffer();
    qbuffer.append("select data from com.a.b.c.Data as data");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch data.mgr mgr");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch data.tmgr tmgr");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch data.comp comp");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch data.myent myent");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch myent.par pardata");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch data.slabs slabs");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch data.tpr tpr");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch tpr.par par");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch par.LE_EN le");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch le.RAT ler");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch data.cd c");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch data.crd crd");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch crd.coc coc");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch coc.thpr cocthpr");
    qbuffer.append(" left join fetch cocthpr.par cocpar");
    qbuffer.append(" where data.dataid = :dataid ");

    Query query = getSession().createQuery(qbuffer.toString()).setLong("dataid", dataid);

    return (Data)query.uniqueResult();
}
```

Can somebody please explain? If needed I will provide the HBM mappings (Lazy/eager etc.). Note->There was no other modification done on anything other than the converion from Criteria to HQL.

Comment: Any quick answers will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you compare the generated SQL?

Comment: I did, but its too different..

Comment: Should ideally the generated query vary in hql comparef to criteria?

Comment: I would expect the criteria one to have much more joined tables, you might be able to conclude what other relations are fetched when compared to HQL one.

Comment: I went through many forums and blogs and it's a debatable topic that hql and criteria should take same time for execution vs hql takes lesser compared to criteria. Some forum says hql is fastet from the 2nd hit onwards because of the caching. On contrary criteria creates alias for every hit and slows down. But in my case I am getting the performance gain from the first hit itself. Do you see any difference between the two queries?

Comment: I had missed to add the Fetch mode in the criteria queries -

Comment: I had missed to add the Fetch mode in the criteria queries -                                     [CODE]public final Data getData(final Long dataid) {
Criteria dataCriteria = session.createCriteria(Data.class)
.setFetchMode("mgr", FetchMode.JOIN)
.setFetchMode("tmgr", FetchMode.JOIN)
.setFetchMode("comp", FetchMode.JOIN)
.createAlias("myent","myent", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
......[/CODE]                                       Does this help any one to answer my previous questions?